# How to get parent id of an anchor tag using prototype?

Tags: javascript, html, prototypejs

```
Event.observe(window, 'load',
function() { 

    $$('a.tag_links').each(function(s) {
        //alert(s.parent.parent.id); //How to get id of its parent to parent
    });
}
);
```

I want to get the id of the parent element.

Structure is something like this.

```
 <div class="home-page" id='entity-1'>
    <div class="index-page-category">

    <a href="/entities/category/food" class="tag_links">food</a>

</div>
```

Result should be entity-1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Like this:

```
    $$('a.tag_links').each(function(s) {
        var parentid = $(s).up('div').id;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your HTML is incomplete. Does it look like:

```
<div class="home-page" id='entity-1'>
    <div class="index-page-category"></div>

    <a href="/entities/category/food" class="tag_links">food</a>

</div>
```

Or like this:

```
<div class="home-page" id='entity-1'>
    <div class="index-page-category">

       <a href="/entities/category/food" class="tag_links">food</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Either way, you should be able to achieve this by using:

```
$$('a.tag_links').each(function(s) {
   var divId = $(s).previous('div.home-page').id;
});
```

I imagine the reason you're iterating through 'a.tag_links' is that you have a bunch of links? Based on that context, is that HTML structure always consistent (the outter div will always contain a class of 'home-page')?

Comment: @rickp $(this).closest is not a function
this is the error i am getting. and i added $ sign here ie $$('a.tag_links')

Comment: @nickp That's jQuery i believe

Comment: Ah, sorry. You should use .previous('div.home-page').id;

Comment: are you sure? According to the Prototype documentation, `previous()` returns the previous sibling, not the ancestor of the element