# Getting farthest (oldest) ancestor by class name with Prototype

Tags: prototypejs, traversal, ancestor

I've wasted way too much time on this today. Let's assume I have something like this:

```
<div id="p1" class="hit">
<div id="p2" class="no-hit">
<div id="p3" class="hit">
<div id="p4" class="no-hit">
<div id="p5" class="hit">
el
</div></div></div></div></div>
```

So my element is being passed to a function, and if it's a descendant of a .hit element, I want `el` to equal the oldest ancestor with the hit class (in this case #p1).

In jQuery, it would be as simple as using el.parents(".hit") and pointing to the last one, but I'm working on legacy code and have to use prototype. The following code works on jsfiddle, but causes an illegal token error on production:

```
if(item.up('.hit') != undefined){
  while(item.up('.hit') != undefined){
    item = item.up('.hit');
  }
}
```

Please prototype, tell me you have an easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: Perhaps the difference between jsfiddle and your production site is the strictness of the doctype.

Answer (score 0):

Prototype and jQuery are similar in this regard (at least, in my interpretation of the documentation). You should be able to use the .up method in Prototype as well.

The code you provided should work with Prototype as well. You can see an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289103/how-to-get-parent-id-of-an-anchor-tag-using-prototype).

If not, you could always try the .previous method.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(typeof item.up('.hit') != 'undefined') {
  while(typeof item.up('.hit') != 'undefined') {
    item = item.up('.hit');
  }
}
```